# Should I use configMap for every environment variable?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I am using helm right now. My project is like that:

**values.yaml:**

```
environmentVariables:
  KEY1: VALUE1
  KEY2: VALUE2
```

**configmap.yaml:**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: {{ template "myproject.fullname" . }}
data:
{{- range $k, $v := .Values.environmentVariables }}
  {{ $k }}: {{ $v | quote }}
{{- end }}
```

**deployment.yaml:**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: {{ template "myproject.fullname" . }}
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: {{ .Chart.Name }}
          image: "{{ .Values.image.repository }}:{{ .Values.image.tag }}"
          imagePullPolicy: {{ .Values.image.pullPolicy }}
          env:
{{- range $k, $v := .Values.environmentVariables }}
            - name: {{ $k }}
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: {{ template "myproject.fullname" $ }}
                  key: {{ $k }}
{{- end }}
...
```

But right now, I'm really confused. Am I really need this configmap? Is there any benefit to use configmap for environment variables?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Aside from the points about separation of config from pods, one advantage of a ConfigMap is it lets you make the values of the variables accessible to other Pods or apps that are not necessarily part of your chart.

It does add a little extra complexity though and there can be a large element of preference about when to use a ConfigMap. Since your ConfigMap keys are the names of the environment variables [you could simplify your Deployment a little by using 'envFrom'](https://gist.github.com/troyharvey/4506472732157221e04c6b15e3b3f094)

Comment: I didn't know that envFrom exists. I use my ConfigMap with other pods and this is a great way to do that. Thank you.

Comment: "make the values of the variables accessible to other Pods or apps that are not necessarily part of your chart" which is not a good thing for security reasons. If sharing was the purpose then one would create a separate chart with just the ConfigMap to be used by all the pods.

Answer (score 7):

It would work even if you don't use a configmap, but it has some advantages:

- You can update the values at runtime, without updating a deployment. Which means you might not need to restart your application (pods). If you don't use a config map, everytime you update the value, your application (or pod) will be recreated.
- Separation of concerns, i.e. deployment configuration and external values separated

Comment: I don't think I can update values at runtime. Environment variables in a pod can't be updated without restart. But separation of concern is a good point.

Comment: A release includes app and its configuration. If you deploy the configuration separately how are you going to keep track of the revisions for the app, and how will you rollback to a previous state if needed.

Comment: It depends on the practice you follow. I've seen it to be pretty common now that mere configuration changes are not considered as part of the release. 
Yes, in that case you would need to revert both, app and config revisions, but a CI/CD process could handle that

Comment: As @yozel pointed out , changing configMaps wont change pod's env variable at runtime , forget about Java changing Configurations at runtime

Answer (score 6):

I feel like this is largely a matter of taste; but I've generally been avoiding ConfigMaps for cases like these.

```
env:
{{- range $k, $v := .Values.environmentVariables }}
  - name: {{ quote $k }}
    value: {{ quote $v }}
{{- end }}
```

You generally want a single source of truth and Helm can be that: you don't want to be in a situation where someone has edited a ConfigMap outside of Helm and a redeployment breaks local changes.  So there's not a lot of value in a ConfigMap being "more editable" than a Deployment spec.

In principle (as @Hazim notes) you can update a ConfigMap contents without restarting a container, but that intrinsically can't update environment variables in running containers, and restarting containers is so routine that doing it once shouldn't matter much.